# additing value to array without array_push

Tags: php

Hi have the following function to add to an existing array

```
function push_curr_value($push_this_value, &$list) {
   $list[] = $push_this_value;
   foreach($list as $value) {
      echo $value."<br />";
   }
   echo sizeof($list);
}
```

but it does not seem to work. the size of the array `$list` remains the same.

And calling the function with the following code:

```
$list = [];
if(array_key_exists('push_value', $_POST)){
   push_curr_value($_POST['push_value'], $list];
}
```

Comment: Please add code where you call this function.

Comment: @Syscall added where function is called

Comment: Whats your desired output? And whats the current output?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm trying to append a new value to an existing array `$list[]`. Currently, what `$list[] = $push_this_value;` does is to just assign the value to `$list[0]`. I want everytime I run the function, I would add another item in the array, and without using `array_push`

Comment: Your code is correct. If you execute multiple times, the arraysize is growing, and the output does what you said it should.

Comment: In your example you are only calling it once, so it is always index 0.

Comment: I think manohars answer shows, that it theoretically works. Or you should update your question if we misunderstand you.

Comment: Use `count` instead of `sizeof`, because it is theoretically faster.

Comment: And what is the deal with `array_push`? Why avoid?

Comment: I have a button to add the value of a textbox, but it only grows to 1 and nothing more

array_push is fine but, the problem I was given was not to use the built-in array function, that is why I'm here looking for other options.

Comment: @Jonathan Well if you are interested is telling the OP to use `count` as its faster than `sizeof` then using `$arr[] = $xxx;` is faster than `array_push($arr,$xxx)` as it does not have the overhead of calling a function. Unless you are going to push multiple things all at the same time `array_push($arr, $one,$two,$three)` use `$arr[] = $xxx;`

Comment: @JeromeAdmana can you write your own array_push method to bypass the instruction requirements?

Comment: @JeromeAdmana what do you mean by "size of array remains the same"? Is it 0 or 1? If you only call it once, how could it not remain the same, assuming it's 1?

Answer (score -1):

```
function push_curr_value($push_this_value, &$list) {
   $list[] = $push_this_value;
   foreach($list as $value) {
      echo $value."<br />";
   }
   echo sizeof($list);
}

public function do_this(){
        $num = [1,2,3];
        $this->push_curr_value(4,$num);
    }
```

Output:-
1
2
3
4
4

Comment: The given code does not produce any output, unless you remove "public" and call `do_this()`. And `$this->push_curr_value`? You have no class here. Please add explanations.